# Hiding images based on alt tag or src

Tags: css

I think I'm losing my mind, since I can't get this simple thing to work.

I have an image in 100s articles which does not work and I want to hide it based on it's alt tag or the src.

Here's a link to my live website: http://www.gamingnewsmedia.com/news-articles/sources-faze-clan-to-leave-wesa/

Feel free to check the source code. I have added exactly the CSS code below.

```
Random Text
<div class="img-div img-div-center">

<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1543872" 
src="http://assets1.ignimgs.com/2015/05/27/contentplaceholderpng-967b4c.png" 
alt="WESA_splash_master" 
width="1280" height="520" 
data-original="http://oyster.ignimgs.com/wordpress/stg.ign.com/2016/05/WESA_splash_master.jpg" />

</div>
More random text
```

My solution is simple:

```
img[alt="WESA_splash_master"] {
display:none;
}
```

This should work, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? Same with the src attribute, I can't get it to work.

Comment: Your JSFiddle works fine for me. What's the problem? Put CSS in the CSS area though.

Comment: you'd put your css code into javascript code so that's why it didn't work, isn't it?

Comment: an updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ue7t8fdo/2/

Comment: Oops sorry about that, but that has nothing to do with my actual live website, since it doesn't work there. http://www.gamingnewsmedia.com/news-articles/sources-faze-clan-to-leave-wesa/
Feel free to check the source code.

Comment: Okay, I see WordPress is escaping ```img[alt="WESA_splash_master"]``` to ```img[alt=\"WESA_splash_master\"]``` This could be a possible issue. And what's with the down vote on a valid question?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

The WordPress theme that I had installed, escaped the quotes inside of `img[alt="WESA_splash_master"]` and turned it into `img[alt=\"WESA_splash_master\"]`
I installed a css plugin called "Simple Custom CSS and JS" which does not escape CSS.